# Redirection Issue using Auth Component

Tags: php, cakephp

I have my home screen with Login Form and Registration button at the following location -

http://localhost/myproject/user/login

When user clicks on Register button, the page is re-directed to -

http://localhost/myproject/user/register

where I have Login Form on the top of the page and Registration Form at the bottom. Now when I fill the login form and submit, if the login fails, user is redirected to

http://localhost/myproject/user/login

instead, I want the user to be redirected to

http://localhost/myproject/user/register

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something in your Users_Controllers like so...

NOTE: I have not tried it and I am not sure it works... I can repost later after trying this...

First you need to turn Auto Redirect to False

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    //...
    function beforeFilter(){
         parent::beforeFilter();
         $this->Auth->autoRedirect = FALSE;
    }

    function login(){
        if( !(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user() ){
            //...
        }else{
            //If useR didnt/cant login redirect to register
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'));
            // Or if you have routes setup for /register
            $this->redirect('/register');
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this helps you out. If not I will try some things later and repost
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you add code examples, we might be able to better help you.

It sounds like you have one of the two issues:

1. You have forms or submit buttons with the same ID's or names.
2. Your forms are posting to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

When the login fails, are you really *redirected* to /user/login ? Or is the login form action url always pointing to the /user/login page, meaning that if the login fails, you just *stay* on this page because you are already on it when you check the credential ?

If I'm right, you could obtain what you want by checking the referer in the /user/login action when the login fails and in this case redirect to /user/register if the referer is /user/register.

Answer (score 0):

Turn of autoRedirect in beforeFilter and redirect manually

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
}

function login()
{
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost()
    {
        if ($this->Auth->user()
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect('/users/register');
        }
    }
    // ... 
}
```